# How to cancel running pipelines using azure devops restapi?

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I tried to cancel the running pipeline using api call, pipelines are configured  using yaml file on azure devops , but when i run my code the pipeline was still running and it didn't cancelled. I used api call using python to azure devops pipeline to cancel the running pipelines. Below url is the end point that i have used for api call. I have used definition id in build id which i guess is same.

url_cancel= [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/build/builds/%7BbuildId%7D?api-version=6.0)

**Python code**

```
data = {"status":"Cancelling"}
                    a = json.dumps(data)

                    # Post request to rest API
                    response = requests.request("PATCH", url_cancel, headers=headers, data=a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cancel the running build, you can use the Rest API: [Builds - Update Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/update-build?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=6.0
```

Here is the Python sample:

```
import requests
import json
import base64

pat = 'PAT'
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')



url = "https://dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{PROJECT}/_apis/build/builds/{BUILDID}?api-version=6.0"



payload = json.dumps({
  "status": "Cancelling"
})

headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  
}

response = requests.request("PATCH", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Update:

My Result:

[image]

Comment: I used the same code but it didn't stopped my running pipelines.

Comment: @AliHaider Can you try to use my sample and test it again? The Rest API is PATCH method, but in your question , the method is POST method.

Comment: i tried with the same sample that has been posted by you, it didn't stopped my running pipelines. I have used "PATCH" method instead of "POST".

Comment: Are you using classic pipeline or YAML Pipeline? And when you run the Sample, can you see any error message?

Comment: Can you update your question and share the steps you running the Rest Api?

Comment: I am using using pipeline which is configured with YAML file, and no error message is displayed.

Comment: Test the sample with YAML , it can work too. see the update. Can you update your question about your steps to run the Python sample?

Comment: I have updated my question and i want to cancel running pipelines using API call.

Comment: Are you running this script in the pipeline or externally？You may try to use PostMan to run this API first and check if it could work

Comment: I am running this externally from a different IDE. from there i have setup connections to azure devops using python.

Comment: can you share the screenshot about how you run the sample? Test multiple times to run the sample in command line , it always work in my side.

Comment: I am not using command line i am using python script to stop the pipelines which are configured on azure devops. But it seems python script is not able to stop the pipelines which are running.

Comment: Sorry. i mean that I use the cmd to run the python file(python script). The python script can stop the pipelines.

Comment: I run pipeline using end point api call from python.